# Word for internalizing excessive critique & acting upon it

Tags: psychology

When a parent or a person of authority excessively critizises a child like "you  never get your homework on time" even if this was a false accusation the child will internalize those remarks and begin to act upon them and as a direct result to the remarks never getting their homework on time.

Is there a word in psychology to describe this phenomenon?

Answer (score 2):

One adjective given in [Lexico (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/self-fulfilling) is

> **self-fulfilling**
>   ADJECTIVE
>
> bound to be proved correct or to come true as a result of behaviour caused by its being expressed.
>
> *Children often know what is expected of them, and believing that children will behave poorly can lead to a **self-fulfilling prophecy.***

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-fulfilling-prophecy) has the phrase

> **self-fulfilling prophecy**
>   *noun*
>
> something that you cause to happen by saying and expecting that it will happen

Comment: Sadly, Lexico is broken.